# Git not recognizing any remote branches

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-remote

First, I've been using Git for about 3 days total my entire life. I've read a lot, and I understand the basics a bit.

So we're trying to setup a staging server. The workflow should look like this "local -> staging -> live"

My local machine can connect to the git repo and it sees all the branches, and allows me to push the branches. The live server can see the branches and pull/merge. The staging server was able to clone the master and can see remotes/origin/{and a few other things here}. But the staging server doesn't see all the branches.

I've tried to fetch, I've hard reset, I've setup a tracking branch, and any other thing SO and google have suggested. I have no idea how to proceed here.

This is my output for "branch -a" locally:

```
$ git branch -a
* all-to-staging
  choose-all
  country-route
  master
  select-to-autocomplete
  sharebuttons
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/all-to-staging
  remotes/origin/choose-all
  remotes/origin/country-route
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/select-to-autocomplete
  remotes/origin/sharebuttons
  remotes/origin/tablesaw
  remotes/origin/wrapping-blockquotes
```

This is my result on staging:

```
# git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/live
  remotes/origin/master
```

I can even see the all-to-staging branch:

[image: all-to-staging]
``

How can I get my staging site to recognize the all-to-staging branch so I can pull it and have people see the change?

Comment: Did you try `git fetch --all`?

Comment: You need `git remote -v show` and you probably want to explicitly name your remotes something other than `origin`

Comment: Why use a name other than `origin`?

Comment: That is, how does it help in this case?

Comment: I've tried fetch --all. I think what's going on is that origin is set to the live site, and not the git repo :/

Answer (score 7):

So I figured it out, hopefully this might help someone else out later.

using `git remote -v` I realized that my origin was pointing to the live site, and not to my repository.

With this knowledge I follwed this guide https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/ to change the remote url with the following commands:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/{my username}/{my repo}.git
```

SSH is similar, if your repo is private it might be better to do it this way

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:{my username}/{my repo}.git
```

Check your origins with `git remote -v`, you should see your new origin url

Now there's 2 things to do here, the proper thing, is to make a new directory and Pull your repo down again so that git is basically set up right, that looks like this:
    cd ..
    mkdir {new project directory}
    cd {new project directory}
    git clone git@github.com:{my username}/{my repo}.git
    git branch -a
    git checkout {your branch name}
    git pull

The second way is trickier because you might run into issues, but sometimes a projects setup is super complicated and it's worth taking the risk before having to set it up again. (This is what I had to do to solve my issue)

Check for branches with `git branch -a`, if you still don't see your branches, then you need to fetch `git fetch` and then you should see your branches, and you can switch to your selected branch with `git checkout`

it would look like this:

```
git branch -a
{no branches shown}
git fetch
git branch -a
{all branches shown}
git checkout {your-branch-name}
git pull
```